# Cordova camera plugin works on emulator and not on Android device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-emulator, phonegap

I'm building an app that allows the user to take photos. I'm using Cordova - JS/CSS/HTML - to write the script. The Cordova camera plugin works perfectly on my Android emulator in Android Studio, but I can't get it to work on my device. Here's what I'm working with:

> IRL Phone: Samsung Galaxy S9+
>
> Cordova version: 10.0.0
>
> Cordova camera plugin version: 5.0.1
>
> PhoneGap cli-6.5.0 (iOS 4.3.1 / Android 6.1.2 / Windows 4.4.3)

I'm not sure if it has something to do with an inconsistency in the build (I heard Cordova versions can have an effect on plugins in certain environments) or if my code is just not friendly for a real Android device.

Here's the plugin code:

```
let app = {
    init: function(){
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', app.takephoto);
    },
    takephoto: function(){
        let opts = {
            quality: 80,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            cameraDirection: Camera.Direction.BACK,
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 400
        };

        navigator.camera.getPicture(app.ftw, app.wtf, opts);
    },
    ftw: function(imgURI){
        document.getElementById('msg').textContent = imgURI;
        document.getElementById('photo').src = imgURI;

    },
    wtf: function(msg){
        document.getElementById('msg').textContent = msg;
    }
};

document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.init);
```

Here's the HTML that runs the script on the app's page from the file camera.js in a separate folder:

```
        <div class="page">
            <p class="code"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="image" id="photo" /></p>
            <p class="node"><button id="btn">Take Picture</button></p>
            <p id="msg"></p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/camera.js"></script>
```

And here's the information in my head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
media-src *; 
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
img-src 'self' data: content:;">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" /> 
<title>4-Point Inspection</title>
```

Maybe this has something to do with the XML or build files? This is my first Cordova app so I'm a little new to this. Any ideas why it works on emulator and not on my Galaxy S9+?

**EDIT**: I have gone ahead and added my config.xml (found in \platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Whitelist">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
</widget>
```

And here is the AndroidManifest (found in \platforms\android\app\src\main):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

Comment: please share `config.xml` and `AndroidManifest`.

Comment: Aside of providing the two files.. Whats the Android Version on your Emulator and Real Device?

Comment: I went ahead and added the config.xml and AndroidManifest from the "main" folder of the android app. I added the code to the end of the original post. I hope those are the correct ones (I noticed there are a few config.xml's among all the folders). Additionally, I use Android version 10 and my emulator is Pixel XL, API 30.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting camera check user allows inapp permission for Camera, like your day to day social apps requests at very first time you open camera after installing the app. Before that goto app manager and enable camera permission and check if camera opens.

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions to get inApp permissions but only for android not for ios

Comment: When I check out the app info, it doesn't list the camera as a permission at all. Like the option doesn't exist. It just says "no permissions required," which obviously doesn't sound right. Do you think adding the Android Permissions plugin you mentioned would remedy that?

Comment: I faced the same issue.. in latest androd versions you need to get permission from user at runtime. Camera permission will be added to manifest automatically. First go to app settings and allow Camera. If it works fine then use the plugin to get permission at runtime

Comment: Sounds good thanks. When I go to app settings for the current app, there is no option for camera or any permissions at all. I have not touched the plugin permissions app you sent. Will adding that plugin give me the ability to allow camera permissions?

Comment: is the camera permission is off or not there? if the permission itself is not there then this plugin won't help. If the permission is there and is off then this plugin will definitely yes.

Comment: When I check the permissions of the app, nothing is listed and it says no permissions are required.

Comment: your camera permission is not in manifest add that first.

Comment: is it not <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ?

Comment: going to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226920/discussion-between-saravanan-and-thecrabnebula).

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your widget tag since your android namespace is missing `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`

```
<widget id="com.your.app.id" version="1.0.0"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```